# Postman cannot read my get and post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

At the same time the data is not saving in the data base... and when i hit send in postman with post request he give me html page instead of json. All settings in postman are properly configure.

**classesModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const classes = new Schema({
    classStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    studentName: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select your status'],
    },
    reason: String,
});

const Class = mongoose.model('Class', classes);
module.exports = Class;
```

**classROuter.js**

```
 const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { class_get, class_post } = require('../controllers/classController');

/* Routes */
router.get('/', class_get);
router.post('/', class_post);

module.exports = router;
```

**classController.js**

```
    const Class = require('../models/classesModel');

const class_get = (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/class/class');
    // res.send('class page');
};

const class_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { status, reason } = req.body;
    try {
        await Class.create({ status, reason });
        res.status(201).json({
            status: 'successful',
        });
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err); //!
    }
};

module.exports = {
    class_get,
    class_post,
};
```

**app.js**

```
app.use('*', checkUser);
app.use('/', homeRoutes);
app.use('/class', requireAuthentication, classRoutes);
app.use('/records', requireAuthentication, recordsRoutes);
app.use('/media', requireAuthentication, mediaRoutes);
```

Comment: I already figured out this by disabling my route authentication. And now it works fine!